# sitecore webpage shows old content which is not present in .net mvc view.I don't want to show that content on web page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore

I am creating page in sitecore.It shows previously published content on page which is now not present anywhere in code.I want to remove that content.Also it does not show header and footer even I give correct placeholder name from layout file.

Answer (score 0):

There might be few possible reasons for it, which you need to verify in your cms to fix this issue:-

1: You might added Sitecore level caching, verify below points in CMS.

i) Sitecore Rendering level cache.

ii) Sitecore page Presentation level cache.

iii) Code level caching

2: Do IIS reset with the below command in CM:-

```
CMD Window> iisreset
```